# Wrong SELECT , I wonder why?

Tags: sql

I wonder where is something wrong with this select:

```
SELECT  dcodigo, dtercero, dvalordeb, dvalorcre, tipo1, tipo, numero,dfecha, ddetalle1
FROM diario
WHERE anulado=@noanulado 
AND (MONTH(dfecha) BETWEEN @per1 and @per2) 
AND (dcodigo BETWEEN @cta1 and @cta2) 
AND YEAR(diario.dfecha)=@anocontable 
ORDER BY dcodigo,dfecha
```

The problem is no show all records that should be. There are more than 100 records with MONTH(dfecha) between per1 and per2

```
If use MONTH(dfecha) > @per1 , show all records fine.  
If use MONTH(dfecha) < @per2 , show all records fine.
```

But when use `(MONTH(dfecha) BETWEEN @per1 and @per2)` it doesn't show any records

What is wrong?

Comment: The other conditions must also be true since you are using AND.

Comment: can you provide some sample data.